# Bignum overflow error after Euler #2 attempt

Tags: lisp, stack-overflow, tail-recursion, bignum

I've attempted to solve [Euler Problem 2](http://projecteuler.net/problem=2) with the following tail recursive functions:

```
(defun fib (num)
  (labels ((fib-helper (num a b)
         (cond ((or (zerop num)
                    (eql num 1))
                a)
               (t (fib-helper (decf num)
                              (+ a b)
                              a)))))
    (fib-helper num 1 1)))


(defun sum-even-fib (max)
  (labels ((helper (sum num)
         (cond ((oddp num) (helper sum (decf num)))
               ((zerop num) sum)
               (t (helper (+ sum (fib num))
                          (decf num))))))
    (helper 0 max)))
```

Now, when I try to print the result using the function

```
(defun print-fib-sum (max dir file)
  (with-open-file
      (fib-sum-str
       (make-pathname
         :name file
         :directory dir)
        :direction :output)
    (format fib-sum-str "~A~%" (sum-even-fib max))))
```

with a `max` value of `4000000`, I get the error

```
     ("bignum overflow" "[Condition of type SYSTEM::SIMPLE-ARITHMETIC-ERROR]" nil)
```

from `*slime-events*`. Is there any other way to handle the number and print to the file?

Comment: After compilation the algorithm took about 60 mins (error of a few minutes- I was monitoring `top` periodically).

Comment: Look at the answer of SDS and then reread the problem. I've linked it in the text.

Comment: Thanks, will do, I've been mixing terms with values in my approach.

Answer (score 3):

First, a few small issues:

1. Use [`time`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_time.htm) instead of `top`.
2. Common Lisp standard does not require tail recursion optimization. While many implementation do it, not all of them optimize all cases (e.g., [`labels`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_flet_.htm)).
3. Your algorithm is quadratic in `max` because it computes the nth Fibonacci number separately for all indexes. You should make it linear instead.
4. You are computing the sum of even-indexed numbers, not [even-valued numbers](http://projecteuler.net/problem=2).

Now, the arithmetic error you are seeing: 4,000,000th Fibonacci number is pretty large - about `1.6^4M` ~ `10^835951`.  Its [length](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_intege.htm) is about `2,776,968`.

Are you sure your lisp can represent bignums this big?

Comment: Shouldn't the limitation on bignum size relate to available resources?

Comment: @Sylwester: it does relate to the resources, but it is possible that there are other limitations, e.g., `integer-length` must be less than 2^31.

Comment: @Bracket: if you have further problems, please ask a new question. "moving target" questions are frustrating and lead to downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

So I've solved Euler #2 with the following tail recursive code:

```
(defun rev-sum-even-fib (max-val)
  (labels ((helper (sum a b)
             (cond ((oddp a)
                    (helper sum (+ a b) a)) 
                   ((> a max-val)
                    sum)
                   (t
                    (helper (+ sum a) (+ a b) a)))))
    (helper 0 1 0)))
```

Here, the algorithm is linear in `max` and evaluates in

```
(time (rev-sum-even-fib 4000000))

Real time: 3.4E-5 sec.
Run time: 0.0 sec.
Space: 0 Bytes
```

Where I've omitted the numerical answer for obvious reasons.

Comment: Here I've used the correct Fib values; Fib(0)=0 and Fib(1)=1.

Comment: You don't need to pass `max-val`, since that variable is lexically available. Edited.

Comment: you don't need to quote numbers, they are *self-evaluating*.

Answer (score 0):

Since CL does not promise that it supports TCO (for example ABCL on the JVM does not support TCO - tail call optimization), it makes sense to write it portably as a loop:

```
(defun rev-sum-even-fib (max-val)
  (loop for a = 1 then (+ a b) and b = 0 then a
        until (> a max-val)
        when (evenp a) sum a))
```